# Converting rads to degrees using 6,28 rad as a caceling factor , what is wrong in my calculation?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I use ^ to indicate exponentiation.

3x 10^-4 rad . (36 x 10° / 6,28 rad) ---here I multiply to cancel the rads so

3 x 10^-4 . 36 x 10° . 62, 8 x 10 -- here I raised the 6,28 as 62,8 x 10 I do the calculation

3 x 10^-2 . 36 . 62,8 = 67,824° firstly I elimate the "tens" and multiply the factors, but this isn't right

Comment: But don't you have to *divide* by the $6.28$ radians? Also $6.28$ is *not* $62.8 \cdot 10$ it is $62.8/10.$ [I'm using period instead of comma as the "decimal point", since that;s the way I do it, I know some countries use comma.] Finally maybe the approximation $6.28$ to $2 \pi$ isn't accurate enough.

Comment: instead of dividing by 6,28, I passed the term to the numerator as 62,8 x 10^-1. turning  the exponent the  positive, +1 the 10^-1 as 10^1.

Comment: But in the numerator $6.28 \cdot 10^{-1}$ or the other one $62.8 \cdot 10^{-1}$ has first few digits $6,2,8$ because multiplying by $10^{-1}$ or first by $10$ only changes where the decimal point ends up. On the other hand dividing by $6.28$ has first few digits $1,5,9$ which won't match what you did.